# Transferring file from local computer to remote server

Tags: linux, shell-script, scp, ftp, sftp

I would like to transfer a `zip` file from my local server to a remote server. I used the following command which contain host, port, and username as follows:

`scp "$somepath/${file}.zip" "$ftp_user"@"ftp_server":upload/`

In this command:

```
   ftp_user=royal
   ftp_server=np.royal.com
```

This command is failing to connect. Would you please advise me?

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: no error message it take its time and loss the connection.

Comment: What _exactly_ does it report back to you?

Comment: Connection time out lost connection and error : FTP transfer fail

Comment: The error messages you reported ("time out", "connection lost", and "FTP transfer fail" indicate that your scp command is either not connecting to the remote host at all (networking issue) or the remote host is not serving the ssh/scp protocol. Given the confusion between scp and FTP, what method to you *expect* to be able to use to transfer the file, and are you certain that the remote server has that service running? Can you ping that remote server?

Comment: when i ping like ping hostname and it keeps on running and i dint receive any data, infact still ruining.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a connectivity problem.

Answer (score 2):

`scp` uses the SSH protocol to transfer files, so it needs an SSH account.

Looks like you need to connect to the server via FTP, so you should use one of the many
ftp clients.

I've always liked [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) best.

Comment: will try to connect using lftp.

Comment: i have changed from scp to lftp in the above code and it is showing command not found FTP fails -<>

Comment: @NirmolenduSingha you have to install `lftp` first, and the syntax is different. thale a look at the link I posted in the answer for usage instructions.

Comment: Do we have any command without installing anything

Comment: @NirmolenduSingha you can try `ftp` which is very limited but should be present in nearly every system.

Comment: Thanks I tried with ftp and it showing as ftp : command not found

Comment: @NirmolenduSingha well, if it's an FTP account you really need to install an FTP program...

Comment: how can i check ftp is installed on local as well as remote server

Comment: @NirmolenduSingha is the server YOUR server? Or you only were given username/password access? In the latter case, FTP should be already installed on the server (as they've given you and ftp_username) and you only need to install an FTP program on your machine.

Comment: yeah that correct so i need check in my local machine

Comment: how can we check in local machine and if not installed where i will get the setup

Comment: @NirmolenduSingha It depends on your OS. Try searching on the internet for an FTP client for your system

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `$` before variables name, so they are not expanding to the correct values you set.

try

```
scp "$somepath/${file}.zip" "$ftp_user"@"$ftp_server":upload/
```

Comment: and the target folder should under `/` like, `/upload` or `/some/dir/upload`

Comment: I tried with Target :/upload but not working